# Ajax not working on window safari?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I have the following code :

```
jQuery.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"",
            data:jQuery("#payment").serialize(),
            success:function(data)
            {
            alert(data);
            //return false;

            }
            });
```

Working fine  on all browser except window safari. This code is working fine on mac safari also

Comment: The Windows version of Safari was discontinued

Comment: just curious, is windows safari that popular in your locale @rakesh to test against?

Comment: Client requirement that's why we are testing on this. @Daemedeor

Answer (score 1):

I was doing an asynchronous post, and Safari stops running the JavaScript (due to the page being unloaded) before it issues the request. after making  setting async to false. It works

```
jQuery.ajax({
            async: false,
            method:"POST",
            url:"",
            data:jQuery("#payment").serialize(),
            success:function(data)
            {
            alert(data);
            //return false;

            }
            });
```